# Powershell - Organise Folders Based on Name

Tags: powershell, directory

I have been looking in how to move folders into sub folders based on there names alone in powershell, each folder contains multiple images with random names.

Folders have names like:

```
/bob.builder.housing.Project/
/racing.jenason.button.driver/
/working.project.bob.builder/
/f1.jenson.button.racing/
/instructions.bob.builder.house/
/random.not.matching/
```

I need to compare these folder names against and list of names and move the folder if it matches

name.txt contains...

```
bob.builder
jenson.button
```

New structure should look like:

```
/jenson.button/racing.jenason.button.driver/
/jenson.button/f1.jenson.button.racing/

/bob.builder/bob.builder.housing.Project/
/bob.builder/working.project.bob.builder/
/bob.builder/instructions.bob.builder.house/

/random.not.matching/
```

I can't work out how to compare the folder names and moved based on them into there corresponding folders.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with `LS` which is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` then pipe that to `Get-Member` and that should be enough to search for some examples. Take one of those examples, work with TEST data and post back what you've come up with.

Comment: `gc 'r:\name.txt' | %{ mkdir "r:\$_" -force >$null; move "r:\*$_*" "r:\$_" -force -ea silent }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code.
It gets the names of the folder, for each one it'll try to make the folder in case that it doesn't exist. Then, it'll move folders that match with it basename.

```
Get-Content 'names.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
    IF (-not (Test-path $_))
    {
        New-Item -Name $_ -ItemType Directory 
    }
    $foldername = Get-Item $_

    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Exclude $_ | ForEach-Object {
        IF ($_.BaseName -match  $foldername.basename  ) 
            {
                Move-Item  -Path $_ -Destination $foldername
            }
    }
}
```